# Designing a protocol for commands and data over serial

Tags: serial-port, protocols

I need (to design?) a protocol for communication between a microprocessor-driven data logger, and a PC (or similar) via serial connection. There will be no control lines, the only way the device/PC can know if they're connected is by the data they're receiving. Connection might be broken and re-established at any time. The serial connection is full-duplex. (8n1)

The problem is what sort of packets to use, handshaking codes, or similar. The microprocessor is extremely limited in capability, so the protocol needs to be as simple as possible. But the data logger will have a number of features such as scheduling logging, downloading logs, setting sample rates, and so on, which may be active simultaneously.

My bloated version would go like this: For both the data logger and PC, a fixed packet size of 16 bytes with a simple 1 byte check sum, perhaps a 0x00 byte at the beginning/end to simplify recognition of packets, and one byte denoting the kind of data in the packet (command / settings / log data / live feed values etc). To synchronize, a unique "hello/reset" packet (of all zero's for example) could be sent by the PC, which when detected by the device is then returned to confirm synchronization.

I'd appreciate any comments on this approach, and welcome any other suggestions as well as general observations.

Observations: I think I will have to roll my own, since I need it to be as lightweight as possible. I'll be taking bits and pieces from protocols suggested in answers, as well as some others I've found... [Slip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Line_Internet_Protocol), 
[PPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Protocol) and [HLDC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDLC).

Comment: I hope you find something, but most of the time I just end up using my own.  Unfortunately, the code on the microcontroller needs to be very limited, so serialization libraries become too heavy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microcontroller Interconnect Network (MIN) is designed for just this purpose: tiny 8-bit microcontrollers talking to something else.

The code is MIT licensed and there's embedded C and also Python implementations:

https://github.com/min-protocol/min

Answer (score 8):

You can use Google's [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) as a data exchange format (also check out the [C bindings](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-c/) project if you're using C). It's a [very efficient](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/encoding.html) format, well suited to such tasks.

Comment: Except that Protocol Buffers doesn't do any checksumming, which might be useful if you're talking over RS232 or (even worse) some wireless connection.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't try to invent something from scratch, perhaps you could reuse something from the past like [ZMODEM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZMODEM) or one of its cousins?  Most of the problems you mention have been solved, and there are probably a number of other cases you haven't even though of yet.

Details on zmodem:
http://www.techfest.com/hardware/modem/zmodem.htm

And the c source code is in the public domain.